# Javascript not working on specific versions of IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, alert, ietester

I've a rare issue with IE. I'm trying to create a page that launches this script when IE version is lower or equal than IE 8 (just a simple alert and a location). When I try to debug this html on IETester the alert only shows up on IE 5.5 and IE 6 but neither in 7 nor 8.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Para poder usar Consumedia necesita tener instalada una version de Internet Explorer 9 o superior');
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    </script>   
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this on IE7 and IE8 and for me the above code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is showing me the alert with native IE7.

It seems IETester might have a [bug](http://www.my-debugbar.com/forum/p3000-2011-02-06-15%3A10%3A14.html) regarding conditional comments. See [How do I make IE9 emulate IE7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7397568/851811) for an alternative to IETester.

@Pekka has already commented on this matter a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840173/851811) of [times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2215285/851811):

> When multiple instances of Internet Explorer are installed (or active) on the same system, conditional comments will be resolved against the highest IE version available on the system

EDIT: Doesn't really add much, but I've got only IE7 installed, and it also shows the alert with IETester for IE <= 7.

Comment: Gracias! Instead of this I will create a VM to make sure that works with IE 8 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sory for my first answer, a don't realize the real problem.

Try to change the if statement:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    //Fires for IE8 and above
<![endif]-->
```

See the examples here:
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: windows.location = "http://www.google.com"; should also works then why there us a need for href

Comment: That's not the issue. I tried to comment this line and the alert doesn't show up. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem though. The `alert` comes before changing the location.

Comment: @red_alert No it's not. On the same page is the statement I put.

Comment: @frikkio You're right, your code is fine. Is better to test it in the 'real' IE8. I have a Virtual Machine with IE8 and WinXP. I've checked and your code is right and fires the alert.